# Applying rules in Telerik MVC Grid Filter

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

I'm using Telerik MVC Grid, and need to apply filter rules below, but it seems only apply to the first two column, and ignore all the rest of the columns.

Here JS Code : ( assume grid is $("#grid").data("tgrid") )

```
function extTelerikGridFilter(grid, value) {
    if (!$.isArray(grid.columns)) throw "Error : First Parameter accept only array.";

    var colLength = grid.columns.length - 1;
    var filterText = "";

    var tempArr = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
        filterText = filterText + "substringof({0},'{1}')".replace("{0}", grid.columns[i].member).replace("{1}", value);
        if (colLength > 0) {
            filterText = filterText + "~or~";
            colLength = colLength - 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(filterText);
    grid.filter(filterText);
}
```

Result of console.log(filterText) :
**substringof(Doc_No,'Opriyandi')~or~substringof(Type,'Opriyandi')**~or~substringof(Request_By,'Opriyandi')~or~substringof(Request_Date,'Opriyandi')~or~substringof(Department,'Opriyandi')~or~substringof(Plant,'Opriyandi')~or~substringof(Description,'Opriyandi')~or~substringof(IT_Support,'Opriyandi')~or~substringof(Status,'Opriyandi')

Look before and after applying the filters in attachment.

Is this some kind of bug or perhaps i did something wrong.. Thank You.

*Using Telerik MVC 2011.3.1229
*Please ask me if you need additional information regarding my issue. :)

Attachment :
- [BeforeApplyingFilter.png](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/254/331120beforeapplyingfil.png/)
- [AfterApplyingFilter](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/860/331121afterapplyingfilt.png/)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. After some experiments, I found that we should bracket every expression starting from the head.

So, your filter string would look like this:

```
(((((((((substringof(Doc_No,'Opriyandi'))~or~substringof(Type,'Opriyandi'))~or~substringof(Request_By,'Opriyandi'))~or~substringof(Request_Date,'Opriyandi'))~or~substringof(Department,'Opriyandi'))~or~substringof(Plant,'Opriyandi'))~or~substringof(Description,'Opriyandi'))~or~substringof(IT_Support,'Opriyandi'))~or~substringof(Status,'Opriyandi'))
```

You can modify your code:

```
..
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
        -->    filterText = "(" + filterText + "substringof({0},'{1}')".replace("{0}", grid.columns[i].member).replace("{1}", value) + ")";    <--
        if (colLength > 0) {
            filterText = filterText + "~or~";
            colLength = colLength - 1;
        }
..
```

PS I'm using 2011.3.1306

**PS2** I wrote the article about custom filtering - please see [link](http://vgolovchenko.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/telerik-mvc3-grid-custom-filtering/).